# jQuery get html selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

I've been searching online for a while trying to find a solution to this. What I want to do is convert text selection start and end points to their equivalent html selection values.

Example:

```
HTML: test text **some <span style="color:red">te**st t</span>ext
TEXT: test text **some te**st text
```

So say the user selects the parts surrounded in ** above. I have no problem getting the position of the text selection: start: 10, end: 17. But what I want to get is the position of the selection including the html elements: start: 10, end: 41

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

EDIT: as requested I've attached my existing code which gets the start and end points of the selected text. What I want to get are the start and end points of the selected HTML.

```
        var start = 0, end = 0;
        var sel, range, priorRange;
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
                range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                priorRange = range.cloneRange();
                priorRange.selectNodeContents(el[ 0 ]);
                priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
                start = priorRange.toString().length;
                end = start + range.toString().length;
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
                (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
                range = sel.createRange();
                priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
                priorRange.moveToElementText(el[ 0 ]);
                priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
                start = priorRange.text.length;
                end = start + range.text.length;
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried.  Having a bit of difficulty understanding the question.

Comment: It's rather hard because the user isn't really selecting the HTML and it's already been parsed by the browser so it doesn't really exist as HTML anymore but DOM elements. Might be possible to for example start counting letters using the HTML content and skipping tags.

Comment: Be mindful of html entities like &amp; will be one character selected but multiple in html. And adjacent spaces will be one selected character but multiple in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is the solution I have come up with. It gets the normal text selection points and then primitively converts to html points. This will probably only work for basic cases but it's all I need for my application.

```
        // this gives me a cross browser start and end position
        // for the text selection
        var start = 0, end = 0;
        var sel, range, priorRange;
        if( typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" ){
                range = window.getSelection( ).getRangeAt( 0 );
                priorRange = range.cloneRange( );
                priorRange.selectNodeContents( el[ 0 ] );
                priorRange.setEnd( range.startContainer, range.startOffset );
                start = priorRange.toString( ).length;
                end = start + range.toString( ).length;
        }
        else if( typeof document.selection != "undefined" && ( sel = document.selection ).type != "Control" ){
                range = sel.createRange( );
                priorRange = document.body.createTextRange( );
                priorRange.moveToElementText( el[ 0 ] );
                priorRange.setEndPoint( "EndToStart", range );
                start = priorRange.text.length;
                end = start + range.text.length;
        }

        // now, get this in terms of html selection
        var html = el.html( ), text = 1, htmlstart = 0, htmlend = 0;
        for( var i = 0, t = 0; i < html.length; ++i ){
                if( html[ i ] == '<' || html[ i ] == '>' ){
                        text = text ? 0 : 1;
                        continue;
                }
                if( text )
                        t++;
                if( t == start )
                        htmlstart = i + 1;
                if( t == end ){
                        htmlend = i + 1;
                        break;
                }
        }
```